# How to capture block of line

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

Kindly help me to capture a block of text from given text

```
file = '''
#--------------------------------------------------
echo "Ethernet Tunnel Configuration"
#--------------------------------------------------

hi
sd
ss
ds
dsd
s
#--------------------------------------------------
echo "Ethernet Rings Configuration"
#--------------------------------------------------
dsihdis  ads sdah

dsidsi 
shids 
sihdh 
#--------------------------------------------------
echo "PYTHON Configuration"
#--------------------------------------------------
'''
```

in the above lines, I want to capture only **echo "Ethernet Rings Configuration" block.**

Kindly help me how can I et it in python.

I tried like below but somehow I am not getting output as expected

```
import re
cisco_command = re.search(r'echo "Ethernet Rings Configuration"', file, re.DOTALL).group(1).strip()
    print(cisco_command)
```

**expected output**

```
#--------------------------------------------------
echo "Ethernet Rings Configuration"
#--------------------------------------------------
dsihdis  ads sdah

dsidsi 
shids 
sihdh
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `re.findall` here:

```py
block = re.findall(r'(#-+\r?\necho "Ethernet Rings Configuration"\r?\n#-+\r?\n.*?)(?:#-+|$)', file, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(block)
```

This prints:

```
['#--------------------------------------------------\necho "Ethernet Rings Configuration"\n#--------------------------------------------------\ndsihdis  ads sdah\n\ndsidsi \nshids \nsihdh \n']
```

Comment: what if echo "Ethernet (Rings) Configuration". how to take care of ( ) inside ""

Comment: @DhananjayaDN Nothing special, just escape the `(` and `)` with backslash.